# How can I transfer contacts between SIM cards?

Tags: iphone, contacts, sim

I've bought a new iPhone 5S and inserted a nano SIM into it by purchasing a nano sim with same number. How can I get contacts from my old sim to new SIM?

Comment: On an iPhone, all of your contacts are stored locally. OR in settings under phone there should be an option to transfer all sim data/contacts locally on your phone.

Comment: What phone or device were you using your old SIM with, and are you sure the contacts are on the SIM not in the device's own memory? Most phones now default to storing contacts on the device not the SIM - and that data should still be accessible even when there is no longer a valid SIM in the device. It might well be that via the SIM is not the best way to transfer your contact info, and exporting or sending it from the old device to your computer or iPhone would work better.

Comment: Check this, https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202340

Answer (score 1):

in an iPhone you can not put addresses to the sim card, only from the sim card to the phone. You can use an "old" phone form before they were smart (e.g. Nokia): copy the addresses into the phone from the sim card 1, put another sim card 2 in and read the addresses into this sim card.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways you can do that:

- thru a mobile device (phone, tablet, computer, etc.);
- via a SIM card reader on your computer with specific software;
- A device for clonning SIM cards.

Please specify the way you want to work so we can provide you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

On the home page of your iPhone, click on the Settings icon

Go to Mail/Contacts/Calendars

Scroll down and you will get the "Import SIM Contacts" option

Start importing your contacts and once it is done, simply change your SIM card